# Mod Rewrite - Clean URL with query string not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have the following .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex api.php
    FallbackResource index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2&id=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2&id=$3&endpoint2=$4 [L]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1/$1.php  [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)? $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2&id=$3%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? $1/$1.php?endpoint=$2&id=$3&endpoint2=$4%1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to rewrite api endpoints (clean url format with possible query at end of last token) into a query string format entirely as shown below.

Example

```
api/users/123/actionitems
```

currently reads

```
api/api.php?endpoint=users&id=123&endpoint2=actionitems

{
    endpoint: users,
    id: 123,
    endpoint2: actionitems
}
```

But I also want to convert

```
api/users/123/actionitems?test=3
```

into

```
api/api.php?endpoint=users&id=123&endpoint2=actionitems&test=3

{
    endpoint: users,
    id: 123,
    endpoint2: actionitems,
    test: 3
}
```

It doesn't work.  I get only

```
api/api.php?endpoint=users&id=123&endpoint2=actionitems
```

when I type

```
/api/users/123/actionitems?test=3

{
    endpoint: users,
    id: 123,
    endpoint2: actionitems
}
```

And only when I type `/api/users/123/actionitems&test=3` instead of question mark  (`/api/users/123/actionitems?test=3`) in my request it works.

**How do I get this to work?**

Comment: Try removing the leading slash you have in the pattern of your second last rule . `RewriteRule ^  **/** ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?` .

Comment: Still same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following single rule :

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex api.php
    FallbackResource index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  /api/api.php?endpoint=$1&id=$2&endpoint2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It works!  but I still need a tweak to allow for the 1 or 2 token case as in the question

Comment: @Vahe this should work for both urls `api/users/123/actionitems?test=3` and `api/users/123/actionitems` .

Comment: I modified the rule and posted a second answer, but I will award you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working rule (so far...)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex api.php
    FallbackResource index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^api/$ /api/api.php? [L]
    RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/$ /api/api.php?endpoint=$1%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /api/api.php?endpoint=$1&id=$2%1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /api/api.php?endpoint=$1&id=$2&endpoint2=$3%1 [QSA,L]
    #Disgard tokens after 3rd token
    RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$  /api/api.php?endpoint=$1&id=$2&endpoint2=$3%1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```